# Streaming mode vs block mode

Tags: compression, lossless-compression

I can't figure out what exactly is the *streaming mode* offered by modern compression/decompression algorithms (eg ZStandard or LZ4) and how I can exploit it.

As an example, suppose I have `4x16KB` file. I can (individually) compress each file and obtain `4xDifferentCompressedLength` files. However I could compress all 4 files together (sending them sequentially, right?) using *streaming mode* and obtain `1xCompressedLength` and expect the compression ratio to be better.

Can I decompress (say) only the 3rd file without decompressing all the previous files? Do *streaming mode* introduce dependency between the files I appended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, streaming introduce dependency between files.
In your example, decoding `file3` would require to decode first `file1` then `file2`.

Note also that data will appear as appended, with no specific marker between files. So one would need a way to know where each file starts and ends if it's important. Sometimes it's implicit (ex : fixed 16KB size), sometimes it can be deducted from data itself (specific end-of-mark), sometimes it needs additional metadata. It all depends on the application.

You are correct that the compression ratio of `C(4xFiles)` is expected to be better than `4xC(File)`, especially if the 4 files are somewhat related (for example if they all are text files).

Comment: Thanks (Yann). Nice feature to transfer (to stream!) data with a better compression ratio.

Comment: how to map **STREAM/BLOCK** to **STATEFUL/STATELESS?**